# Get the maximum $key value from array with keys ($key -> $value) for every unique $value in php

Tags: php

i have an $array with keys like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 462
    [2] => 462
    [3] => 462
    [4] => 462
    [5] => 19
    [6] => 19
    [7] => 19
    [8] => 462
)
```

where 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 are keys and 462,462,462,462,19,19,19,462 are values. I want to get the *maximum* key for every *unique* value, so, the result must be an array like:

```
Array
    (
        [7] => 19
        [8] => 462
    )
```

How can i get maximum $key for all the unique $values? I know i can get the maximum key and maximum value with:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $keys[] = $key;
                $values[] = $value;
}
echo "max key is - ".max($keys);
echo "max value is - ".max($values);
```

But it is not exactly what i need. So what can be a solition?

Answer (score 5):

Just using `array_flip()` will first reduce all of the duplicates to 1 element (arrays can't have more than one key with the same value), so ...

```
$a = [1=>462,462,462,462,19,19,19,462];
print_r(array_flip($a));
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [462] => 8
    [19] => 7
)
```

You could use `array_flip()` again to swap the keys/values...

```
print_r(array_flip(array_flip($a)));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [8] => 462
    [7] => 19
)
```

Comment: Nice, yep this is the way to go, due to the key collision you'll get your unique values, I'll be using this in the future! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make an array `$maxis` takes keys of the unique *value* and store them as elements.

```php
$array = [1=>462, 2=>462, 3=>462, 4=>462, 5=>19, 6=>19, 7=>19, 8=>462];
$maxis = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $maxis[$value][] = $key;
}
```

```
/*
462: [1,2,3,4,8]
19: [5,6,7]
*/
```

Loops over `$maxis` and store maximum of `$arr_keys` as key, and `$key` as its value.

```php
$res = [];
foreach ($maxis as $key=> $arr_keys) {
    $res[max($arr_keys)] = $key;
}
print_r($res);
```

*Prints:*

```
Array
(
    [8] => 462
    [7] => 19
)
```